# Ensuring XFS volumes on GCE / GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'd like to run several stateful applications (such as MongoDB, Kafka, etc.). All of them recommend using XFS as file system, however I don't know how I can ensure the creation of a XFS file system in Google's Kubernetes Engine / Google Cloud Compute Engine.

I usually deploy my applications with a helm chart and I couldn't find any hints that it would take care of the XFS filesystem for me either.

**Question:**

Can someone explain me how I can ensure the creation of XFS volumes in GKE / GCE / Kubernetes?

Comment: Choosing EXT/XFS can make a difference for performance, fault-tolerance and reliability on physical machines. The difference between XFS and EXT in the cloud with network attached storage disks is minor today. You may be trying to chose XFS when it really does not matter for Kubernetes. For Kubernetes, you want to design your systems (nodes) to be independant of the underlying storage, networking and compute infrastructure.

Comment: Interesting John. Can you explain why it doesn't matter on kubernetes. Because mongodb and other providers highly recommend to use xfs.

Comment: Can you show me a link where they recommend XFS for Google Cloud or AWS or Azure with real data supporting the recommendation? I am not aware of any independant studies that show strong benefits using XFS in the cloud over any other file system. Note I am not trying to start an "opinion war". There are many benefits for rack mounted servers in a data center. For Kubernetes, applications should not (do not) need to be aware of the underlying storage beyond IOPS and Volume Size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment using XFS as file system on Google's Kubernetes Engine is not supported, but there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/62613829) to enable Support XFS on Container-Optimized OS (when choosing COS).
Therefore, you can choose Ubuntu node image for your XFS needs, check this [link](https://medium.com/@allanlei/mounting-xfs-on-gke-adcf9bd0f212).

Answer (score 0):

"Limited" support will be available (for XFS) from COS-85 onward.

See: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/supported-filesystems

The work-around to get xfs support in your COS < 85 is normally not worth the time and effort. Until then, you have to live with ext4.

(COS = Container-Optimized OS)

I have the following in Feb 2021:

```
gke-myproject-production-pool-1-12345-abc ~ #  date
Fri Feb 12 11:28:56 UTC 2021

gke-myproject-production-pool-1-12345-abc ~ # cat /etc/os-release
BUILD_ID=12871.1218.0
NAME="Container-Optimized OS"
KERNEL_COMMIT_ID=5319ad296f69c96f28ec39084d94927beab6b8e3
GOOGLE_CRASH_ID=Lakitu
VERSION_ID=81
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/resources/support-policy#contact_us"
PRETTY_NAME="Container-Optimized OS from Google"
VERSION=81
GOOGLE_METRICS_PRODUCT_ID=26
HOME_URL="https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs"
ID=cos
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, Feb 2022, "Container-Optimized OS comes with a fully-supported XFS filesystem starting from COS M105" ([source](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/supported-filesystems#xfs)). Thus if this is the OS of your GKE nodes, the XFS filesys is now fully supported.

Here is the GKE documentation on "[Using the Compute Engine persistent disk CSI Driver with non-default filesystem types](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/gce-pd-csi-driver#non-default-fstype)". The example it gives allows for creating XFS persistent disks in GKE using the CE CSI driver.

I have used it successfully to create such a disk for MongoDB, as it recommends XFS in production. However, based on some very early performance testing, there seems to be no benefit & in fact some signs of worse performance than EXT4, so make sure you do your own testing to check for any side effects :)